# Observer for mass product attribute queues

Tags: magento2, event-observer, message-queue

I would like to do some extra custom actions after a product price is changed.
I was thinking to use the `catalog_product_save_after` event when a mass price update is done from the **Product Grid -> Actions -> Update Attributes** (via the `bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update`).
I've created the `events.xml` file in the `etc` folder with this content:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
        xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="catalog_product_save_after">
        <observer name="catalog_product_save_after_queue"
                  instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\ProductSaveAfterQueue"/>
    </event>
</config>
```

This is my `ProductSaveAfterQueue` content:

```
use Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class ProductSaveAfterQueue implements ObserverInterface
{
    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $writer = new \Zend\Log\Writer\Stream(BP . '/var/log/custom.log');
        $logger = new \Zend\Log\Logger();
        $logger->addWriter($writer);
        $logger->info('Here');
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, my log file is not created :(  Do you know why and what kind of event or approach should I use instead ?

Thanks

Comment: Please move your events.xml file under path etc/adminhtml/. After that please check by insert die() in observer file

Comment: Hi @ZealousWeb i moved it under the `etc/adminhtml/` folder, I added the `die()` and also kept my log script. But nothing. The price is updated , seems like the observer is not fired. Not sure why.

Comment: Please use this event "catalog_product_attribute_update_before"

Comment: @ZealousWeb `catalog_product_attribute_update_before` works but only if I add the event in the etc folder not etc/adminthml. Is there an after event ? I've tried using `catalog_product_attribute_update_after`, but doesn't work. Weird

Answer (score 0):

Try using the event `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save` the way the module `Magento_cacheInvalidate` is using to invalidate the caches (see `vendor/magento/module-cache-invalidate/etc/events.xml` for details).

Comment: Hi @Diana, thanks for your post . But I am using message queue , which runs via crons .The event: `controller_action_postdispatch_adminhtml_catalog_product_action_attribute_save` seems to fired only from the controller.

Comment: but why? you mentioned you wanted to track the price change from admin product grid.

Comment: That change will add a new record in the `queue_message` table. The `bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update` will do that actual update

Comment: i see, but then you shouldn't care when the queue is processed, you should basically intervene at the point where the message is published to the queue #justsaying (and that is the action and implicitly the event mentioned above), unless i am missing something.

Answer (score 0):

For Bulk updates, you can use a plugin as well/instead which should work as the event does not seem to be triggered.

In your modules di.xml

```
<type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_product_attribute_save_update_name" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product\AfterAttributeUpdate"/>
</type>
```

Then AfterAttributeUpdate.php contains something like

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Product;

use Magento\Catalog\Model\Product\Action;

class UpdateDiscogsAfterAttributeUpdate
{
    public function __construct(
       // Inject any deps here
    ) {
    }

    /**
     * @param Action $subject
     * @param $result
     * @param array $productIds
     * @param array $attrData
     * @param int $storeId
     * @return Action
     */
    public function afterUpdateAttributes(Action $subject, $result, array $productIds, array $attrData, int $storeId)
    {
        foreach ($productIds as $productId) {
            if (array_key_exists('price', $attrData)) {
               // Do update here
            }
        }

        return $result;
    }
}
```

To debug you can run

```
bin/magento queue:consumers:start product_action_attribute.update
```

to listen for the bulk updates coming from the queue.

Hope that helps